# update a select query in oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 5 tables in a DB like this (script below)::

[image]

DB SCRIPT

```
CREATE TABLE EQUIPE (
    code_equipe char(3) primary key,
    nom varchar(30),
    directeur varchar(30));
CREATE TABLE PAYS (
    code_pays varchar(3) primary key,
    nom varchar(20));
CREATE TABLE COUREUR (
    num_dossart number(3) primary key,
    code_equipe char(3),
    nom varchar(30),
    code_pays varchar(3));
CREATE TABLE ETAPE (
    num_etape number(1) primary key,
    date_etape date,
    kms number(3),
    ville_depart varchar(20),
    ville_arrivee varchar(20));
CREATE TABLE TEMPS (
    num_dossart number(3),
    num_etape number(1),
    temps_realise number(6),
    primary key(num_dossart,num_etape));
ALTER table COUREUR add CONSTRAINT FK_avoir_code_equipe FOREIGN KEY (code_equipe) REFERENCES EQUIPE(code_equipe);
ALTER table COUREUR add CONSTRAINT FK_avoir_code_pays FOREIGN KEY (code_pays) REFERENCES PAYS(code_pays);
ALTER table TEMPS add CONSTRAINT FK_avoir_num_dossart FOREIGN KEY (num_dossart) REFERENCES COUREUR(num_dossart);
ALTER table TEMPS add CONSTRAINT FK_avoir_num_etape FOREIGN KEY (num_etape) REFERENCES ETAPE(num_etape);
```

and my query

```
select num_etape,max(temps_realise) from TEMPS group by num_etape
```

gave this result

[image]

and i want to update it to give result like this

[image]

this is

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: share text sample data and expected output

Comment: DDL as text not as link to an image

Comment: If you expect any answers, you need to provide DDL, Sample data, your query and expected results _as formatted text_ not images please.

Comment: ok im a newbie here so im gonna update this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question thanks guys

```
select num_dossart,nom,num_etape,dernier from COUREUR C,
(select num_etape ,max(temps_realise) as dernier from TEMPS GROUP BY num_etape) T 
where num_dossart = 
(select num_dossart from TEMPS where temps_realise = dernier )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly, a simple join does the job:

```
select t.num_etape, 
       c.nom, 
       max(n.temps_realise)
from temps t join coureur c on c.num_dossart = t.num.dossart
group by t.num_etape, 
         c.nom;
```